# CheckConstraint checking that the sum of fields do not exceed a value

Tags: django, django-models

How should one approach writing a `CheckConstraint` for model that triggers when the sum of two fields exceeds the value of another?  I am able to do a `CheckConstraint` that triggers when the value of one field exceeds another.  How do I adapt that to include summation? (i.e. to modify `check=models.Q(entry__lte=models.F("limit"))`, to something like `check=models.Q(F('entry') + F('extra') <= models.F("limit"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[felixxm](https://forum.djangoproject.com/u/felixxm) answered this question at [Django forum](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/checkconstraint-checking-that-the-sum-of-fields-do-not-exceed-a-value/18221/3).  I am adding a copy here for others that may search StackOverflow for a similar challenge.

**You can revert the operator:**

```
check=models.Q(limit__gte=F('entry') + F('extra'))
```